# Sky & Atmosphere for Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

The Blender Manual describes for **Blender Render** extensive setting options for Sky & Atmosphere, like in-scattering, extinction, exposure, brightness, turbidity etc. However, in **Cycles Render** that all seems to be condensed in world => background => sky texture, with only turbidity and albedo as parameters. Aren't there any more functionalities in Cycles Render?

Comment: That's because if you are using cycle as a production tool, you will most likely be also using a hdri or exr format to create Image Based Lighting (IBL) environment. An example of how a hdri IBL look like http://media.hdrmaps.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/620x310/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/r/free-hdri-map-066_1.jpg Some production artist will go so far as to take an image on location and then use it later in their rendering.

Comment: And 3rd party add-ons are available -- from Blender Guru, Dragoneex and others, I am sure... -- providing out-of-the-can Cycles lighting and sky options.

Comment: In Cycles it's done just in another way. **Sky Texture** node is procedural hdri map which may work for testing renders etc. If you add **Environment Texture** you can plug any hdri map you have. For scattering you use special nodes like cegaton answered. Exposure and brightness can be set in different ways, including compositor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For atmospheric/volumetric effects in cycles you have to use volume scattering and volume absortion on the volume section:

[image]

Comment: When I enable volume scatter it become completely dark. What can be a problem?

Comment: @NikitaDemidenko please ask your question on a different post. Use the blue link [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) at the top right of the page.